# Assembly word ptr in 2 cases

Tags: assembly, x86

Here, the first code uses + 1 on dd variable to access the second byte of it I understand,
but the second code I used an array with the same notation + 1 which occurs to me that it is the second element in the array, Is the result really the first byte of the second array element or it will be the first element but its second byte?

first code:

```
    .data
    num dd 090F0433H
    .code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, word ptr num + 1
```

second code:

```
    .data
    num dd 090F0433H,081234FEH
    .code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, word ptr num + 1
```

Comment: Plus 1 here means plus one byte. Also, you're loading words (16-bit entities), not bytes.

Comment: Unlike C, assembly language doesn't *implicitly* scale by the element size.  You have to do that yourself if you want it, and unaligned accesses are easily possible if you want that instead.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError But `dd` means define **double word**.

Comment: @winapiadmin: It does indeed - the data values are dword values, but `ax` is a 16-bit wide register, so it can't hold the full value - `eax` would.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks, but both codes will truncate the value of `num`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be the first element but its second byte.

`num` can be expanded to

```
num db 33h, 04h, 0Fh, 09h,
       FEh, 34h, 12h, 08h
```

and the memory allocation of `num` will be
In both code, register `ax` had been set to `[num + 1]`, then we have value of `ax` is

```
ax db 0Fh, 04h
```

or

```
ax dw 0F04h
```

and full memory dump is `num + 1`, `ax` will be `0Fh`, `04h`, `33h`, ...

And both codes are moving as `word ptr`, so the value of `ax` will be 0F04h, so both codes are equal.

Comment: Remember that x86 is little-endian.  So the equivalent bytes would instead be `num db 33h, 04h, 0fh, 09h, feh, 34h, 12h, 08h`.  But after putting it all back together, the value in `ax` will indeed be `0f04h`.